# create JSONArray in php and send it to android

Tags: java, php, android, json

i'm developing an android project which i need to create a JSON message in my php server and send it to the android devices.

i wrote the following code in php

```
$event_array = array();
// fill the event_array with some data
print json_encode(array('event_array' => $event_array));
```

but the result is like

```
 {
    "event_array": {
        "id_1": {
            "name": "name",
            "logo_address": "logo_address",
            "title": "title",
            "time": null,
            "address": null,
            "address_location": null,
            "explain": null,
            "type": null,
            "id": "id_1",
            "number_of_users": null
        },
        "id_2": {
            "name": "name2",
            "logo_address": null,
            "title": null,
            "time": null,
            "address": null,
            "address_location": null,
            "explain": null,
            "type": null,
            "id": "id_2",
            "number_of_users": null
        }
    }
}
```

and it's not a json array and i get exception in my android code which simply is

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(res);
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("event_array");
```

what's wrong?

thanks for any help

Comment: Use http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/ to know types of JSON

Comment: Try `json_encode($event_array));`

Comment: @Pratik Butani: i try this, but it's not print like a jsonarray and it doesn't have any name :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{ means object, [ means array.

In your case its two objects.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(res);
```

is correct and contains another object called event_array.

```
JSONObject jsonEvents = new JSONObject(jObject.getString("event_array"));
```

while jsonEvents now holds

```
jsonEvents.getString("id_1");
```

which is another jsonObject.

If you want to output as array, use array again.

As written in http://de3.php.net/json_encode it must be something like this to get an array

```
echo json_encode(array(array('event_array' => $event_array)));
```

So it means it should be like this to match your case.

```
 echo json_encode(
    array(
        'event_array' =>
        array(
            array("id_1" => array('name' => 'name', 'logo_...' => '...')),
            array("id_2" => array('name' => '....', 'logo_....' => '....'))
        )
 ));
```

to read this in Java its more likely

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
 JSONArray jsonArr = json.getString('event_array');

 for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonEventData = jsonArr.getJsonObject(i);
 }
```

Comment: i know this! but i want to have a jsonarray and not a jsonobject! i try "echo json_encode(array('event_array' => $event_array)), "\n";" but the result was same as before :(

Comment: i try this too, it's change to [{"event_array":{"id_1":{"name":"name","logo_address":"logo_address","title":"title","time":null,"address":null,"address_location":null,"explain":null,"type":null,"id":"id_1","number_of_users":null},"id_2":{"name":"name2","logo_address":null,"title":null,"time":null,"address":null,"address_location":null,"explain":null,"type":null,"id":"id_2","number_of_users":null}}}]  but the exception still exists. by the way thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: so, its not wrong. You can see how it works. Ill update the answer with an example for your case.

Comment: nop! :((( it doesn't work too :( you can see the result here: http://foroutannezhad.com/temp/events.php